# How are asynchronous controller actions processed by the MVC framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How does MVC handle controller actions that return a task. ie what is the difference between

```
public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()
```

and

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
```

in the way that MVC process it (I do not want an explanation of the difference between these methods in general, only in the context of how the result of these methods is used to create the view for example)

Edit: I don't see any difference in the views that use it. ie there is no indication that it is handle differently. How does MVC handle it internally?

Comment: Lots of docs on this... http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: If you're using Tasks, you should really also be using the `async` keyword (you *may* also need to derive from the `AsyncController` class).

Comment: @martin_costello I am talking about then AccountController for example in MVC 5 where it is not an AsyncController

Comment: Didn't you intend to write `public async Task<ActionResult> MyAction()`?

Comment: @MatthiasMeid yes sorry... It was late at night ;)

Answer (score 2):

Internally, MVC will (asynchronously) wait for the returned task to complete before sending the response.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on this? In particular, once the framework has determined that a particular request routes to an asynchronous action, how does it wait on that action without then blocking the request context's thread? Or is the MVC handler fundamentally asynchronous until it invokes a synchronous action?

Comment: MVC controllers can be handled either synchronously or asynchronously. When I say it "will (asynchronously) wait", I mean that it will not send the response until the task completes, in a way that does not block the thread.